# AWS S3 Go Sdk - Presigned url unable upload file when add ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, acl

I have a go services that generate a presigned url to upload a file:

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(os.Getenv(AwsRegionEnv))},
)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

svc := s3.New(sess)

req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv(BucketNameEnv)),
    Key:    aws.String(getFileName(file, customer)),
})

minutesTimeout, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv(TimeoutURL))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

str, err := req.Presign(time.Duration(minutesTimeout) * time.Minute)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

So, I can upload a file using this presigned url using curl:

```
curl -vT test.pdf '<<URL PRESIGNED>>'
```

But, when I add an ACL, this not work, the modification are:

```
req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv(BucketNameEnv)),
    Key:    aws.String(getFileName(file, customer)),
    ACL:    aws.String(s3.ObjectCannedACLAuthenticatedRead),
})
```

When I tried upload a file using the presigned url with ACL, I got this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
   <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
   <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAS...</AWSAccessKeyId>
   <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210316T135400Z
20210316/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request
d7ab7d377b719636610b11793e3e68e104a3f41fb9f9f5608138a8c2b19ceaf3</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>bd59fbb080..</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>41 57 53...</StringToSignBytes>
    <CanonicalRequest>PUT
/35527810/sampleVpacheco3.pdf
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=...%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20210316T135400Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=300&amp;X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEN7%2F%2F...&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl
host:adl-digital-dev-document-manager.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl:

host;x-amz-acl
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
    <CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54...</CanonicalRequestBytes>
    <RequestId>0V6FWNNGK2QCDA1V</RequestId>
    <HostId>rE4rkv...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any idea how I can add ACL and can upload a file successfully?

Full URL is:

```
https://document-manager.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/35527810/sampleVpacheco5.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIASN3IRSVR%2F20210316%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210316T143240Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEN7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGW4j1R7H3wIxUAN8FytKbDTRne4pJGJ9I4ofpXeh%2FcaAiBFTdRNVug9WODzLdCoMcFRVzFZ%2FtGeaweeteSSTY6yMSqtAwgXEAIaDDE2NzE4NjEwOTc5NSIMh1JvraENxW8E5aBqKooDLx39b6Lx1%2Fw6AtGMSzlYRILNIXdB2Ouviq0pUlfPVCSFlZnPzo%2F%2B6%2B8ZcIpHM8E%2FDjEn1NF1lvcz9QKsuXJI94XuVCSRGiBBRvpIdm%2Ff001q3C%2FmZW2I1aMsfV518LTtEQigJ%2Fv80TPVSv7ZozoR9Zae4W3C3efjm2sJ%2BkVkI%2FBm7z6Vd97Q%2BbpVztf8Lp4GImDp1G72wtOP7wq9wSDYzFEzUja91r7g97py1Wzin6%2BXUNX68yAH%2BRePqyW6by4Lht8086B7YQcj6h77kxwE89C1NMYhKPiNl1y%2Ff4NukwWxW%2FTefqSW3Qr26eDfTV%2FVyR7%2FeNCf7OOtpkGZEmOnFbd%2FyY6wVOARcTdixQkPKKu2GAkz%2B8xuNY10uTGoh2vul3gUWBZF4Yl13R7kIq%2FPBb1UVl%2BatCwN%2BDBMj22cM4Pn%2BOJPyqxCjcfyIXwRsiYDTmmtiSIWrTvSEQaWf1Dc95lQVToA2ZsAxB8LO88%2FEz0t3FUpPw0ncgbLbHedcRYqvV62RDRQK%2FI9zjCz78KCBjqnAfzDcfP25%2BIr6ia4elbxSDOWIIv%2FjZOLlRDedHdqLKCDjYbgXoWrTQTt%2BZCRlV7UtJxo%2ByVeJvsjmb3BdI4IjI8wd8XjkV5qMejJbFcmFIQV7df0cdGY7U6nOO8gxGK9fj7Fb1Y0DtZaCxaZU8D0d2iTfUn8kl%2FT0GwSPDZqz1I6oJuG58KLR%2BVKRhuZrhTq8%2Fm98cLg7diuwt%2Bt1RwL%2BK9oonqHqXcE&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&X-Amz-Signature=27d1fae2f60187dce85b175980c4e91334fe2a0f192d220244aa4a27e798ec9f
```

I Tired this:

- add header x-amc-acl: -H "x-amc-acl: authenticated-read"
- add header host: -H "host: 127.0.0.1"
- Modify URL, changing `host%3Bx-amz-acl` by `host;x-amc-acl`

Thanks!

Comment: You then need to specify the acl when using the presigned url. Right now the request is signed to "know" of the acl, but the url does not actually contain the acl - only if the one using the presigned url actually provides the correct acl do the signatures match.

Comment: @luk2302 Where in the URL should I include the ACL? Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure, what does the URL look like the second snippet?

Comment: @luk2302 I edited the question and added the full URL

Comment: `X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl` => `host;x-amc-acl` => Try providing a header for `x-amc-acl: authenticated-read` (and maybe the `host`) as well.

Comment: @luk2302 I tired this, but the result is same.

Comment: @luk2302 I add header x-amc-acl, but it is x-am*z*-acl, I change c by z and it's work! Thank!

Comment: Ouch, that was typo from me, yes, obviously `x-amz-...` is correct.

Comment: @luk2302 If you want, you can add an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @victorpacheco3107, have you resolved your issue? Can you please post a complete code so others can get help from your solution. I am struggling with implementing Pre-signed URL implementation with Golang. Your complete solution with helpful comments will be helpful OR if you have GitHub that can also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me after adding acl properties in query param

```
req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
  Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
  Key:    aws.String(key),
})
q := req.HTTPRequest.URL.Query()
q.Add("x-amz-acl", "public-read")
q.Add("Content-Type", contentType)
req.HTTPRequest.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

presigned, err := req.Presign(5 * time.Minute)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("Error presigning URL: %v\n", err)
}
fmt.Println(presigned)
```

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!  FYI, this is a legit bug still after a year: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1692